# How to defer update to firebase from Compose TextField until user enters ImeAction.Done

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to defer updates to Firebase Database only after user press the ImeAction.Done in a TextField.
(Such that the user can update the TextField, but we will update the database only when user press the Done button. )

This however results in 2 sources of truth (one from the temporary user update, and the other from the firebase database).

If I remember the temporary field, user updates are reflected, but it will not update when firebase does the first read/ or when the user selects another path.

```
//PROBLEM: tempDisplayName is only updated once and it will not register changes from firebase.
var tempDisplayName by remember {mutableStateOf(firebaseDataClass?.displayName?:"")} 
  
HoistDisplayName(tempDisplayName, { tempDisplayName = it}, 
     {
         firebaseDataClass?.displayname = tempDisplayName
         updateDatabase(firebaseDataClass)})
```

if I use the firebase field, then  when user selects another path the Db changes are reflected, but user updates to TextField no longer works.

```
//Now the field is updated when user selects another branch on firebase 
//(firebaseDataClass updated). 
//PROBLEM: user updates to the TextField is no longer reflected.
val tempDisplayName = firebaseDataClass?.displayName?:"" 

HoistDisplayName(tempDisplayName, { tempDisplayName = it}, 
     {
         firebaseDataClass?.displayname = tempDisplayName
         updateDatabase(firebaseDataClass)})
```

The following is the Hoisted composable.

```
@Composable
private fun HoistDisplayName(
    display: String,
    onUpdate: (String) -> Unit,
    onDone: () -> Unit
) { 
    val localFocusManager = LocalFocusManager.current 
    OutlinedTextField(value = display,
        label = { Text(text = "Your name") }, 
        onValueChange = { onUpdate.invoke(it) },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions {
            localFocusManager.clearFocus()
            onDone.invoke()
        }) 
}
```

So how do I fix the code such that

1. updates from firebase DB will be reflected on the TextField (replaces all temporary changes)
2. temporary changes are also displayed on the TextField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `remember` + `mutableStateOf` in order to text field to work.

And you need to update it value when your `firebaseDataClass?.displayName` changes. To do so you need to pass this value as a `remember` key: when `realDisplayName` is different from last render time, `tempDisplayName` will be updated with new value.

```
val realDisplayName = firebaseDataClass?.displayName?:""
var tempDisplayName by remember(realDisplayName) { mutableStateOf(realDisplayName) }
```